# unmarshal easy xml

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have simple schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="error"  type="xs:string">
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I generated Java code From XML Schema using JAXB.  I have only one class:

```
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    private final static QName _Error_QNAME = new QName("", "error");

    /**
     * Create a new ObjectFactory that can be used to create new instances of schema derived classes for package: error
     * 
     */
    public ObjectFactory() {
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}}
     * 
     */
    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "", name = "error")
    public JAXBElement<String> createError(String value) {
        return new JAXBElement<String>(_Error_QNAME, String.class, null, value);
    }

}
```

I usually use this code to parse XML:

```
 JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(RootGenerateClass.class);
 Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
 RootGenerateClass response = (RootGenerateClass) unmarshaller.unmarshal(streamWrapper.getStream());
```

What should I do in this case(i don't have any rootGenerateClass)? I try this:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(String.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
String response = (String) unmarshaller.unmarshal(streamWrapper.getStream());
```

of course  it isn't work((

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `ObjectFactory` is in the package `com.example` you should be able to do

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.example");
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
JAXBElement<String> responseElt = (JAXBElement<String>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(streamWrapper.getStream());
String response = responseElt.getValue();
```

When you give a package name to `JAXBContext.newInstance` it will look for an `ObjectFactory` class in that package.

Comment: +1 - If you generate the model from an XML schema then you should create a `JAXBContext` from the package name.  If you are creating the `JAXBContext` from classes you need to include `ObjectFactory` in the list of classes.  I.e. `JAXBContextFactory.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class)`;

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned your `RootGenerateClass` here. Also unmarshling means converting XML Content into JAVA Class Object, and that class should have the data members same as in your XML schema. So, in the second case unmarshling to `String` class object will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot. :) 
i Just use wrapper for root element

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="error" type="RetroErrorType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="RetroErrorType">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

and

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(String.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
String response = (String) unmarshaller.unmarshal(streamWrapper.getStream());
```

working properly